# Abnormal termination of stage in Datastage

Tags: oracle, runtime-error, datastage

I have a DX server job in Datastage v8.1 
It has very simple flow DRS stage --> Transformer --> seq file stage
In DRS stage I have an oracle sql query (complex join query).
I am able to view data through VIEW DATA option in DRS stage but when I execue the job it Aborts saying

```
Abnormal termination of stage Exxx_Ixyxyxy..X_Transform detected
```

There no other error or warning message in log.

Comment: Is Exxx_Ixyxyxy..X_Transform  the name of the transformer stage? If yes have you tested the job without it?

Comment: Hi @MichaelTiefenbacher X_Transform is the transformer stage. Exxx_Ixyxyxy is my job name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem until I cleaned the resources that the job had locked and it works:

From Unix/Linux:

1. Log into the server using the dsadm user.
2. cd to the DSEngine directory
3. Enter . ./dsenv to source the dsenv file
4. Enter ./bin/uvsh to get into DataStage prompt
5. At ">" DataStage engine prompt, enter LOGTO project name
6. Run LIST.READU EVERY to list all the locks
7. Check active record locks under "Item Id" column for job name or RT_CONFIG# or RT_LOG# (# matches the job description number
8. Write down the Inode numbers and user numbers associated with these locks.
9. Enter LOGTO UV

If the LOGTO command is disabled, enter this command

"CHDIR <path_to_the_DSEngine_folder>"

(with <path_to_the_DSEngine_folder>=cat /.dshome under a telnet session on the DataStage server).

The UNLOCK command lives in UV account.

10. Enter UNLOCK INODE inode# USER user# ALL
11. You can use Q to get out of DataStage engine